# Use CTE for update records

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have 2 table1 and table2 and want to update data table 2 from table 1 using CTE

table1

| id | name | class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | xxx |
| 2 | b | vvv |
| 3 | c | eee |

table2

| id | name | class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | xxx |
| 2 | b |  |
| 3 | c |  |

The expect result for table2 after the update:

| id | name | class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | xxx |
| 2 | b | vvv |
| 3 | c | eee |

My CTE

```
With cteupdate as 
(Select Id, Name, class
from table1 t1
join table2 t2
on t1.Id = t2.Id)
Update cteupdate set t2.class = t1.class
```

Returns this error:

> Update or insert of view or function 'cteupdate' failed because it contains a derived or constant field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When both tables have columns with the same name, I don't know that you're going to be able to do that (in fact I'm surprised you didn't get dinged with an ambiguous column name error). How about:

```
UPDATE t2 SET t2.class = t1.class
  FROM dbo.table2 AS t2
  INNER JOIN dbo.table1 AS t1
  ON t1.Id = t2.Id
  WHERE t1.class IS NOT NULL;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4122df5281a67bbe0cf7367c21177213)

I'm not sure why it's so important to use a CTE, and this might be harder for future maintainers to understand why you want this roundabout approach too, but perhaps:

```
;WITH cteupdate AS
(
  SELECT t2.Id, t2.class, newclass = t1.class
    FROM dbo.table1 AS t1
    INNER JOIN dbo.table2 AS t2
    ON t1.Id = t2.Id
    WHERE t1.class IS NOT NULL
)
UPDATE cteupdate SET class = newclass;
```

The main problem (aside from ambiguous column names, which I address by applying a different alias to the "new" `class` column), is that you can't reference `t1`/`t2` outside of the CTE, since all that's left at that point is the CTE.

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=75d2a2e157e16abc64ac79d0b9c7363c)

Comment: But I do like to use with cte. Any work around?